# How to remove a non-nullable field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a `category` field in my model which I want to remove. However it did not have `null=True` so (from previous experience) deleting it will cause a `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column “category” violates not-null constraint` error.

Any way around this?

Here's is the field:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='1')
```

Comment: just remove it and `makemigrations & migrate`

Comment: That only happens if you try to add a new not-null column, not when removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You must be run the `manage.py makemigrations`
And `manage.py migrate`  to apply the changes

Answer (score 0):

By default when you create a new django field and if you don't provide the argument null explicitly, it will be treated as False, so if you don't specified null argument at the creation it will be by default null = False. Just delete the field,save the file and make the python.manage.py makemigrations  and then python.manage.py migrate to reflect the changes you have made to your model in the DB